# python tests: project setup does not find classes from program

Tags: python

I fail to setup my python project for working tests.
Here is my structure:

```
.
├── model
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── user.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── user.py
```

user.py:

```
class User:
    pass
```

test_user.py

```
from model.user import User
```

The error:

```
python test/user.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/minimal_example/test/user.py", line 1, in <module>
    from model.user import User
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

A relative import also fails:

test_user.py:

```
from ..model.user import User

 test/test_user.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/minimal_example/test/test_user.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..model.user import User
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `PYTHONPATH`

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/your/project
python test/user.py
```

you can use `pytest`

```
pip install pytest
pytest test/user.py
```

or unittest:

```
# location --> test/user.py
from unittest import TestCase
from model.user import User

class TestUser(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        User()
```

and inside root directory, where `test` and `model` directories, run test:

```
python -m unittest test.user
```

Comment: so basically it was an mistake how I launched the tests. It's working now.

Comment: Yup, python adds to the pythonpath the parent folder of the script you are trying to run. In this case it is trying to find model.user under the test folder + site-packages & not in your PWD